# Select box not working inside jquery menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Please check this fiddle link why select box in dropdown not working

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fire82wall/f9rbwLy9/)

I am working with this https://jqueryui.com/menu/ 
but my select box not working.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#left_menu").menu();
});
```

```css
ul ,li{
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<ul id="left_menu">
<li><a href="#">Passport(s)</a><ul><li>
     <label for="passport_select">Select Experience</label>
      <select name="passport_select" id="passport_select">
       <option>Conotou</option>
        <option>BOSSMAN A</option>
        <option>BOSSMAN B</option>
        <option>Import</option>
      </select>
      <button class="filter_link" id="passport">SUBMIT</button>
    <br>
   </li></ul></li>
  <li><a href="#">gender</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="filter_link" id="gender">
        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" checked> Male
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female"> Female
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why do you want to put a selection box into a menu?

Comment: just because i am using it like filter

Comment: person can select a country

Comment: Seems like a terrible idea, why don't you just make it another sub-menu instead of a drop-down?

Comment: Looks like you have sort of a form inside a submenu... The UI looks like you should be using tabs... I don't feel like what you have is a menu... or if you must use menu, make the select options a submenu like Seano suggested.

Comment: @Seano666 great idea but list of country is in hundred

Answer (score 0):

Make another sub-menu (instead of a select) and control the overflow with css.  That way you can contain the hundreds of country values in a small space.

```
<li>
    <div class="CountryWrapper">
        <ul>
          <li>BOSSMANA</li>
          <li>BOSSMANB</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>


       .CountryWrapper{          
          overflow-x: scroll;
          height: 200px;
        }
```